# How to show my wi-fi key?

Tags: wireless-networking

[image]

There are key index show how to show key?

[image]

There are enabled key showing.

Comment: Have you tried Nirsoft's [WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Network Password recovery tool by www.nirosoft.net . It is just a small portable tool which list all the network password stored in your System.

The tool can be download from this URL:

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. For security reasons there is no way that is already on your computer to view your key as you enter it or after you're logged in.

Comment: Incorrect. See the other answer.

Comment: No, my answer is correct. "There is no way that is already on your computer"